# How to create sentence with different textStyle in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to define a sentence with the different textStyle in the flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Need more clarity in your question..

But as far as I understood..I believe that you need something like..

A sentence with a mix of different colors and font weights.. something like that..

If that is the case, You can go for `RichText`..
Here is a sample code..

```
RichText(
text: TextSpan(
 text: 'Hello ',
  style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
   children: <TextSpan>[
    TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
   ],
 ),
)
```

You can get more information from the documentation..
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html